# Tag "work-environment" and "job"

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

The tag [work-environment](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-environment) (currently 288 questions) is defined as:

> Use this tag if the question is related to the work environment, such as an issue with your boss, your coworkers, or someone you have authority over.

The tag [job](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job) (currently 11 questions) has no definition.

Can we agree to synonymize those two tags?

If not, can we add a definition to the "job" tag?

Answer (score 4):

As I commented on [Upper_Case's answer](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3632/3171), we have a third related tag: [professionalism](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professionalism). Between that and [work-environment](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-environment), **I think [job](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job) can go.**

Out of the three questions that Upper_Case identified, the only one that I think doesn't fit either [professionalism](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professionalism) or [work-environment](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-environment) is [How to tell a friend I don't want to continue giving him advice?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/20319/how-to-tell-a-friend-i-dont-want-to-continue-giving-him-advice), which is about trying to help a friend get a job. It's not really about jobs so much as [saying-no](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saying-no), which it is already tagged with.

The other two questions:

- [How to decline a job offer from a previous employer, without burning bridges?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/18095/how-to-decline-a-job-offer-from-a-previous-employer-without-burning-bridges)
- [How to ask my old boss who started his own company for a job](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/14391/how-to-ask-my-old-boss-who-started-his-own-company-for-a-job)

I think can both be retagged with [professionalism](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professionalism), as it describes the sort of impression the OP wants to have on the other person.

Since "getting a job" is not an interpersonal skill, and everything else (in my opinion) can be recategorized as some combination of "in a workplace" or "being professional", I don't think we should keep this tag.

<sup>(... but if we do decide to keep it, I think it should be renamed to be plural like our other noun tags ;) )</sup>

Comment: I fully support firing the "Job" tag

Answer (score 1):

From a quick survey, it looks to me like the tags are used mostly interchangeably, but not always.

Of the 11 questions tagged with [job](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job):

- Six are closed or on hold (so I'm not sure they're great
  examples of tag use, since the questions are lacking)
- A couple seem synonymous with [work-environment](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-environment), in that they are "on
  the job" sorts of questions (even if they don't *exactly* match the tag guidance for [work-environment](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-environment))
- A couple seem to be somewhat related to jobs but are not obvious matches
  for [work-environment](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-environment) as currently described
  ([How to tell a friend I don't want to continue giving him advice?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/20319/how-to-tell-a-friend-i-dont-want-to-continue-giving-him-advice),
  [How to decline a job offer from a previous employer, without burning bridges?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/18095/how-to-decline-a-job-offer-from-a-previous-employer-without-burning-bridges),
  [How to ask my old boss who started his own company for a job](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/14391/how-to-ask-my-old-boss-who-started-his-own-company-for-a-job))

It seems to me that many of the questions tagged with [job](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job) are mis-tagged (they should have [work-environment](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-environment) instead), but that in rare cases [work-environment](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-environment) is not appropriate even though questions are related to jobs or professionalism in some way.

I don't know that we should declare that the tags are synonymous (there are at least *some* cases where [job](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job) is used and [work-environment](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-environment) doesn't quite fit), but [job](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job) is being used vaguely as a catch-all.

I'm not sure that [job](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job) is used in a sufficiently consistent way that we can or should attach guidance based on how it's been used so far (for the cases which don't overlap with [work-environment](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-environment)), but we can be more prescriptive about how the tag is defined.

So, I'll agree with your second suggestion: we should add tag guidance to [job](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job) (and all tags, probably, should have some guidance attached). Otherwise we should consider removing the tag altogether.

Comment: Hmm, so we do have a tag for ["professionalism"](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professionalism) already (with a little bit of guidance) - do you think that would cover the remainder of the "jobs" questions?

Comment: @EmC Maybe, and it would definitely be better than "jobs", which as noted here is confusing with "work-environment" also present. I'm not sure that the "jobs" tag has been used very consistently, so I don't know that a single replacement would adequately cover all instances.